# What should be added to calculate and output the increase or decrease of the variable Energy for each behavior?

Tags: java

***What should be added to calculate and output the increase or decrease of the variable Energy for each behavior?
Initial values of Energy: person, student, and student worker are 10, and professional and researcher are 8.***

```
person: speak -2, eat +3, walk -3, sleep +3
student: speak -2, eat +3, walk -1, sleep +3, study -1
studentworker: speak -2, eat +3, walk -1, sleep +2, work -3, study -2
researcher: speak -2, eat +3, walk -2, sleep +3, research -2
professor: speak -2, eat +3, walk -2, sleep +3, research -1, teach -1
```

*Output of the final value in which energy fluctuates according to the behavior at each initial value in the following order.*

- Case 1: Student: sleep–eat–walk-speak- study
- Case 2: Professor: teach-speak-walk-research-sleep
- Case 3: Person: sleep–eat–speak-walk

```java
    class Person
    {
        int Energy = 10;
        void sleep() { System.out.println("sleep"); this.Energy += 3;}
        void eat() { System.out.println("eat"); this.Energy += 3; }
        void speak() { System.out.println("speak"); this.Energy -= 2;}
        void walk() { System.out.println("walk"); this.Energy -=3;}
        
        public void person(int Energy)
        {
            this.Energy = Energy;
        }
    }

    class Student extends Person
    {       
            int Energy = 10;
            void study()
            {
                System.out.println("study");
                this.Energy -= 1;
            }
    }

    class StudentWorker extends Student
    {
        int Energy = 10;
        void work()
        {   
            this.Energy -= 3;
            System.out.println("work");
        }
    }

    class Researcher extends Person
    {   
        int Energy = 8;
        void research()
        {   
            this.Energy -= 2;
            System.out.println("research");
        }
    }

    class Professor extends Researcher
    {   
        int Energy = 8;
        void teach()
        {   
            this.Energy -=1;
            System.out.println("teach");
        }
    }
    
    public class _java {
    
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Person p = new Person();
            
            Student s = new Student();
            System.out.println("Case 1: Student: ");
            p.sleep(); p.eat(); p.walk(); p.speak(); s.study();

            StudentWorker sw = new StudentWorker();
            Researcher r = new Researcher();
            
            Professor pf = new Professor();
            System.out.println("Case 2: Professor: ");
            pf.teach(); p.speak(); p.walk(); r.research(); p.sleep();
            System.out.println();
            
            System.out.println("Case 3: Person: ");
            p.sleep(); p.eat(); p.speak(); p.walk();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi @si1203! Welcome to SO! Just to let you know this site is not about people providing solutions to homework. If you have a specific problem you are having in your code, people are more likely to answer your question. Please provide what issues you are having with your code.

Comment: I don't understand your question. I see that your code is already decrease and increase the energy value.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You should revisit some basic tutorials on [inheritance](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html), [controlling access to the fields](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html), and [constructors](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html) to resolve the following issues in your code:

1. Class `Person` is missing a default constructor, and a constructor with `int energy` parameter (instead of the method `void person` = which should be a setter `public void setEnergy(int value)`)

```java
class Person {
    public Person() {
        this(10);
    }
    public Person(int energy) {
        this.energy = energy;
    }
// ...
}
```

2. Field `energy` does NOT have to be redeclared in child classes `Student`, `StudentWorker` etc. to avoid hiding of this field.
3. If you *really* need the field `energy` to be accessed directly in child classes, you should have declared it as `protected`.

But it is much better to access the field via getters/setters and here you could possibly implement methods like `spendEnergy / gainEnergy` to decrease/increase energy amount:

```java
// class Person
public void setEnergy(int value) {
     this.energy = value;
}
public int getEnergy() {
     return energy;
}
public void spendEnergy(int delta) {
    this.energy -= delta;
}
public void gainEnergy(int delta) {
    this.energy += delta;
}
```

Then use these methods in `sleep, eat, walk` etc to modify the energy and override methods `walk`, `sleep`, etc. as necessary to provide specific values, for example:

```java
// class Person
void eat() {
    System.out.println("eat");
    gainEnergy(3);
}
void walk() {
    System.out.println("walk");
    spendEnergy(3);
}
```

```java
// class Student
void study() {
    System.out.println("study");
    spendEnergy(1);
}
void walk() {
    System.out.println("walk");
    spendEnergy(1);
}
```

```java
// class StudentWorker
void sleep() {
    System.out.println("sleep");
    gainEnergy(2);
}
void study() {
    System.out.println("study");
    spendEnergy(2);
}
void work() {
    System.out.println("work");
    spendEnergy(3);
}

// walk from Student is used with energy spend 1
```

4. The constructors in child classes should set custom value of energy:

```java
class Researcher extends Person {
    public Researcher() {
        super(8);
    }
// ...
}
```